# Object is possibly Null

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to get the id from the url and then use that to navigate to a different specific view
I have the following function

```
getStudent(): void {
  const id = + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.studentService.getStudent(id)
     .subscribe(student => this.SpecificStudent = student);
```

I have tried to make sure it is not null by using the assertion

// !

```
const id = + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
```

If I do this, it doesn’t show an error, but alert(id) gives 0 which is wrong

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I extract I’d as number from the url?

Comment: Error TS2531: Object is possibly ‘null’.                         From that particular line ..const id

Comment: Can you show an example request URI for the call? like `/my/route/104521/etc`

Comment: An example request URL should look something like this Localhost:4200/detail/13

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Number` method:

```js
Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'))
```

Or

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(param => {
      let id = +param.get('id');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two possible solutions:

1. Assign to id if not falsy, otherwise assign something else:

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id') || 'yourDefaultString';
this.studentService.getStudent(id)
.subscribe(student => this.SpecificStudent = student);
```

2. check before passing the argument to the function that is not falsy, if it's falsy we will pass our default string:

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.studentService.getStudent(id ? id : 'yourDefaultString')
.subscribe(student => this.SpecificStudent = student);
```

Comment: The parameter id is of type number.                        And argument of type ‘string’ isn’t assignable to parameter of type ‘number’.

Comment: sorry, but the parameter id cannot be of type number.
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get() takes a string as parameter and returns a string.

If the method getStudent() of the studentService takes only a number, either change the method to accept both numbers and string, or convert the id from string to number by using parseInt()
like this:
this.studentService.getStudent(parseInt(id))

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as

```
const id = + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
id && this.studentService.getStudent(id)
     .subscribe(student => this.SpecificStudent = student);
```